# Facebook login for iOS error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 3.)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

I'm receiving the error code:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 3.)
```

for logging into facebook on my app and am not sure why.  Here is my viewController code:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

@IBOutlet weak var facebookLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  facebookLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    facebookLoginButton.delegate = self

  }

  //MARK: Facebook Login

  func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if error == nil {

      print("Login Complete")

      performSegueWithIdentifier("facebookSegue", sender: self)

    } else {

      print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
  }

  func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("User logged out")
  }
```

Here is the appDelegate:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

      //Facebook login
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

  func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    //Facebook login
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
  }
```

I think the code is correct but maybe I'm missing something, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you upgraded the Facebook iOS SDK to version 4.39.0, there is a bug that causes this error. Downgrade to 4.38.1 will help you solve this problem. Be sure to downgrade both FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'
```

Be sure to clean the build folder and re-build the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out.  The plist file had to be modified as followed:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb</string>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fbauth2</string>
      <string>fbshareextension</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    </array>
```

after adding that it worked!